# JQuery Tablesorter issue

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have this table where the  is initially blank. Then when
the document is ready I call a function that runs an AJAX query for
the table content.
The initial content is sorted awesomely! But when I call my function
again with different parameters to get new content, things start to go
wrong. The table fills with the new content just fine, but clicking
on a header column to sort reverts the table content back to what it
was when the page first loaded and the sorting also stops working.

This is the code snippet that I am using.
will using $('.tablesorter').trigger("update") help? At what point should i make a call to this?

```
jQuery(".tablesorter > tbody").load(path, function(){
    jQuery(".tablesorter").tablesorter({
                    onRenderHeader: function (){
                    this.wrapInner("<span></span>");
                }
                , widthFixed: true
                , widgets: ['zebra','hovering','selected']
                , debug: true
              });
}
```

Thanks,
MM

Comment: How is your new content being put into the table after you get it from your AJAX query?

Comment: I am using 

jQuery("#tablename > tbody").load(path, function(){
}

where "path" is the url for ajax call

Answer (score 2):

I believe you will need to use livequery to let tablesorter know about the new ajax content.

This one took me a while to wrap my head around, but basically this should work, after you include the livequery js:

```
$("#table").livequery(function(){
  $(this).tablesorter({
    ...
  })
});
```

Noah

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to trigger the widgets call this method`$("Table").trigger("applyWidgets");`

This will ensure the all widgets like zebra effects, hovering etc,. will be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
include  $("#table_name").tablesorter(); in ajax call.
```

You need to hook tablesorter functionality via ajax call.

new table contents also would have sorting functionality if you hook in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
$(".tablesorter").livequery(function(){
    $(this).tablesorter({
    .
    .
    .
    });
});
```